# Importing Alexa data into Amazon RedShift

Tags: amazon-redshift, alexa-internet

I have taken the daily dump file and unzipped it and then placed it back up onto s3.

When I try and do a copy statement in postgresql I am receiving the following error

```
Missing newline: Unexpected character  0x14 found at location 4
```

Query:

```
copy temp from 's3://bucket/top-1m.csv' credentials 'blah blah blah';
```

Do I have to add some kinda character to each line?

Raw Data:

```
1,facebook.com
2,google.com
3,youtube.com
4,yahoo.com
5,amazon.com
6,baidu.com
7,wikipedia.org
8,live.com
```

Comment: Delimiter? The default is |

Comment: Default for RedShift or for Alexa?

Comment: Redshift COPY command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Redshift COPY command uses PIPE '|' as the default delimiter character.
If your files are delimited by another character (comma in your case), all you need to do is add the DELIMITER keyword to your COPY command.

`copy temp from 's3://bucket/top-1m.csv' credentials 'blah blah blah' delimiter as ',';`

or for comma separated files:

```
copy temp from 's3://bucket/top-1m.csv' credentials 'blah blah blah' csv;
```

Answer (score -1):

copy temp from 's3://bucket/top-1m.csv' credentials 'blah blah blah' delimiter ',';